# How do I ensure that charts and dataZoom line up in ECharts?

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

**current problem：**

I need to show two polylines in dataZoom, But now what I've achieved is this:

[image: current result]

**expectation:**
dataZoom is the same as shown in the diagram.What should I do?

**Repeat step**

1. access: https://codesandbox.io/s/large-scale-area-chart-forked-ckhtct?file=/index.js

Comment: I dont think this is possible in echarts.